# Unable to start httpd service on Centos 7 "GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject"

Tags: apache, centos, polkit

When trying to (re)start httpd service I get the following error:

```
** (pkttyagent:2574): WARNING **: 01:33:55.345: Unable to register authentication agent:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject Error registering authentication agent:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject (polkit-error-quark, 0) Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then

```
systemctl status httpd.service
```

sheds no light on the problem:

```
httpd.service - Web server Apache
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-07-22 01:33:55 BST; 26min ago
  Process: 2578 ExecStart=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 22 01:33:55 server... systemd[1]: Starting Web server Apache...
Jul 22 01:33:55 server... systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 22 01:33:55 server... systemd[1]: Failed to start Web server Apache.
Jul 22 01:33:55 server... systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jul 22 01:33:55 server... systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

What might be causing this? Where should I look to debug?

Comment: share `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -t` command output.

Comment: `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -t` shows `Syntax OK`

Comment: start Apache using `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start` and let me know result.

Comment: No errors are reported with `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start`

Comment: You check whether the process start or not using `ps -ef | grep httpd`. If the process start successfully then stop the process using `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start` and start using `systemctl start httpd`

Comment: `ps -ef | grep httpd` shows `root     11039 10891  0 05:53 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd` with `httpd` in red. When I stop with `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k stop` the response is `httpd (pid 10372?) not running` so I presume that I haven't managed to start httpd this way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218404/discussion-between-dzseti-and-pandurang).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thu Jul 23 05:40:44.885963 2020] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2877:tid 140514669713280] AH02565: Certificate and private key  do not match

Looks like key and certificate do not match. Please check md5 of the key and cert file.

Comment: Thanks Pandurang :) What was strange was that the 2 certs causing the problem had the same timestamp, but I needed to replace them to get the Apache server started. Can only imagine that the original cert files were corrupted somehow

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when trying to restart a systemd service.

The workaround is as follows:

Run this as root

groupadd -g 23 nohidproc

usermod -a -G nohidproc polkitd

mount -o remount,rw,hidepid=2,gid=nohidproc /proc

systemctl restart polkit